# how to load pickled objects into a list of empty variables?

Tags: python, python-2.7, serialization, pickle

I have a list of variable names, and a list of names of pickled objects:

```
pickle_var_names = object1, object2   # both empty, which throws an error
pickle_names = ['object1', 'object2']
```

I wish to load the pickles called in `pickle_names` into `pickle_var_names`, respectively:

```
for pickle_var_name,pickle_name in zip(pickle_var_names,pickle_names):
    with open(pickle_name,'r') as pickle_fp:
        pickle_var_name = cPickle.load(pickle_fp)
```

How do I do initialize a list of variables to `None` to allow them to be assigned later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are indexed by position, not by name, so you could do this:

```
picklevars = []
picklenames = ['object1', 'object2']
for picklename in picklenames:
    with open(pickle_name, 'r') as pickle_fp:
        picklevars.append(cPickle.load(pickle_fp))
```

Or, if you're able to use a dictionary instead of a list:

```
picklevars = {}
picklenames = ['object1', 'object2']
for picklename in picklenames:
    with open(pickle_name, 'r') as pickle_fp:
        picklevars[picklename] = cPickle.load(pickle_fp)
```